# PHP: Spaces are not shown right

Tags: php, utf-8, space

I have built an PHP application. In the page data is shown in 'Kannada' language.
I see that spaces are shown with a rectangle (or is it a different character?).
Any idea how to set this right?

I have set the encoding as UTF-8 for all pages.

Thanks
Krishna

Comment: Rectangles are usually an indication that the font used doesn't contain that character. What font are you using, and are you sure it defines the character?

Comment: Browsers like IE display a rectangle instead of `�` ... probably a nbsp encoded in cp1252/iso88591 being interpreted as utf-8. Hard to see how a whitespace character would not have font support as it probably doesn't even require a glyph